# How to extract subArray from Array[Array[Int]] column DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ARRAY                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6), WrappedArray(7, 8, 9)]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I use this code to create it:

```
case class MySchema(arr: Array[Array[Int]])
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Array(Array(1,2,3),
          Array(4,5,6),
          Array(7,8,9))))
      .map(x => MySchema(x))
      .toDF("ARRAY")
```

I would like to get a result like this:

```
+-----------+
|ARRAY      |                                                          |
+-----------+
|[1, 2, 3]  |
|[4, 5, 6]  |
|[7, 8, 9]  |
+-----------+
```

Do you have any idea?

I already try to call an udf to do a flatmap(x => x) on my Array line but I get an incorrect result :

```
+---------------------------+
|ARRAY                      |
+---------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|
+---------------------------+
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explode:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}
df.select(explode(col("array")))
```